# Why does only the first option appear in select when using ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, pug

If I have a select that is being populated using ng-repeat and I make two options below the select, only the first appears. Why is this?

Example:

```
<select id="dropDownSelect", ng-model="chosenDash.id", ng-options="dashboard._id as formalTitle(dashboard) for dashboard in dashboards">
  <option value="">This will show up</option>
  <option value="">This will not</option>
</select>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: From the angular docs for [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive: "Optionally, a single hard-coded <option> element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the <select> element"

Comment: why do u need multiple empty options?

Comment: @BenWilde I am populating the select with a list of dashboards the user created. The first hard coded option would act as a placeholder for the select, and the second would be a "New Dashboard" option that once clicked would call a function in my controller. This was just a basic example I threw together

Comment: @OmniTek got it.. alternatively you could have a "New Dashboard" button next to your select. If you really want it to be in the select, then after you populate your `dashboards` array you could add another entry with a unique id and a formal title of "New Dashboard", and then set a watcher on 'chosenDash.id', and if that ever changed to the id corresponding to the "New Dashboard" item, you could run that function in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular only supports one empty (null) option.

See lines 229-235 here - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js:

```
  // find "null" option
  for(var i = 0, children = element.children(), ii = children.length; i < ii; i++) {
    if (children[i].value === '') {
      emptyOption = nullOption = children.eq(i);
      break;
    }
  }
```

As soon as it finds a child element with an empty value attribute, it sets that as the empty option and stops looking. Then the options (including the one empty option) are generated and replace whatever options are in there. Your second empty option is being ignored.